# TryParse doesn't resolve properly

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, resolve

The Facebook API function `FacebookOAuthResult.TryParse()` doesn't resolve. I am giving the correct input parameters for the `TryParse` function. I had added the Facebook library properly under the Visual studio reference for the project. Many functions are getting resolved properly but `TryParse` is not getting resolved. Any clue about this issue?

Comment: Does it seem that the class `FacebookOAuthResult` is valid, at least?  Or is it that it can't recognize anything in the Facebook SDK?

Comment: Are you using Facebook C# SDK? It looks like it doesn't have a TryParse method. Source: https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/blob/master/Source/Facebook/FacebookOAuthResult.cs

Comment: Seems that the Facebook C# SDK has changed a bit.

Comment: Funny because it's in several blog posts...

Answer (score 0):

I noticed there is a ParseOauthCallbackUrl on the FacebookClient object, which returns a FacebookOAuthResult object.  About to implement and try it out, but that seems to be the new location.